# Having issues enabling AJAX on ASP.NET application

Tags: ajax, sharepoint

I have been fumbling with deploying my code to a SharePoint 2007 site for hours. I have ajax in my project and ajax is enabled on the sharepoint server. I am now getting this error:

but its type (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager).

Can someone please help point me in the right direction? I understand that I have some versioning issues... My project was developed in VS 2008 on .NET 3.5, and the SharePoint application is .NET 2.0 with ajax enabled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this to the "runtime" section web.config  of the web application you working on:

under the  "assemblyBinding"" section in the runtime section:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to resolve that is make them the same version... use the .NET 2.0 version; I don't know if you can any other way... the difference between System.Web.UI.ScriptManager is the version.  To test, deploy a sample app using .NET 2.0 with the script manager, and try it out.

Comment: Okay I will try. So if that is the issue, then does that mean I have to set the target framework in my project to 2.0?

Comment: Only problem is that when I pull the ajax stuff out, I still get an unexpected error...